# make background image stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

On [this website](http://festivals.ie) there's a background image in the footer that should stick to the bottom of the page. I don't mean the visible part of the page, but rather the very bottom of the page. However on pages where the content is short - [like this one](http://festivals.ie/artist/list?name=X) - it appears some distance above the bottom.

The CSS that I'm currently using is:

```
html {
  background: url(../images/responsive/bg.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  outline:0!important;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the html and body elements to 100%? E.g. `html, body {height:100%}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking to do is more in-line with the concept of a "sticky footer". [Example](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and [tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Comment: second sentence of question `I don't mean the visible part of the page, but rather the very bottom of the page.`

Comment: Sticky footers can appear "below the fold" as it were.

Comment: As Jonah was pointing to: make that example page very small in height, and you'll see that the footer falls below the page properly, as you want.

Comment: aha, maybe mention that in your answer?

Answer (score -7):

What about using the float attribute:

```
float: bottom;
```

Comment: `float` can only be `none`, `right`, `left`, or `inherit` http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp